# Merge two multidimensional arrays and reindex all subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, reindex

I have two arrays, I want to merge these two arrays into single array. Please view the detail below:

First Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 3
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 1
        )
)
```

Second Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [d] => 4
            [e] => 5
            [f] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [d] => 6
            [e] => 5
            [f] => 4
        )
)
```

I want this result. Does somebody know how to do this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 4
        )
)
```

Hope you have understand the question. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there something wrong with using [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge)?

Comment: @JonStirling Yes there is if you want the result the OP specifies as that will preserve the keys of the original arrays. Note his answer has 0-based indexes for his sub-arrays. Whether that is the result he needs or not only he can answer!

Comment: I don't see a problem with array_merge. Looks like OP: http://codepad.org/Bf5VpZOr

Comment: array_merge function won't give me the result i want. I want 0-based indexes for sub-arrays as liquorvicar said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FIXED** (again)

```
function array_merge_to_indexed () {
    $result = array();

    foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
        foreach ($arg as $innerArr) {
            $result[] = array_values($innerArr);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Accepts an unlimited number of input arrays, merges all sub arrays into one container as indexed arrays, and returns the result.

***EDIT 03/2014:*** Improved readability and efficiency

Comment: This preserves the original keys from the arrays which isn't the result he's looking for (at least not from the data in the question).

Comment: @liquorvicar No it doesn't, that's the point of the function, otherwise I would have just said "use array_merge()". I used `[]` to convert to indexed, although your `array_values()` without the last loop approach is arguably better.

Comment: Ah ok, I did run your code and it didn't work for me but looking at your edited post it must have been an old version that I ran.

Comment: Yeh I posted two slightly wrong versions but I realised they were wrong and fixed them :-)

Answer (score 13):

Try [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect because ot fails to produce the desired result.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/FodoK

Answer (score 2):

more simple and modern way is:

```
$merged = $array1 + ['apple' => 10, 'orange' => 20] + ['cherry' => 12, 'grape' => 32];
```

new array syntax from *php 5.4*

Comment: The array union operator is not suitable for this specific question.  Your snippet will only damage the data.  Proof of failure: https://3v4l.org/XWNmj

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the exact result you specify in your question then something like this will work

```
function array_merge_no_keys() {
    $result = array();
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    foreach( $arrays as $array ) {
        if( is_array( $array ) ) {
            foreach( $array as $subArray ) {
                $result[] = array_values( $subArray );
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Sooo... this is just a copy of the accepted answer with the additional and unnecessary check of `is_array()`?

Comment: @mickmackusa it wasn't a "copy". This answer was originally posted at the same time as the now accepted answer (which was wrong at the time and has since been edited). Whether the additional `is_array()` check is necessary or not depends on the circumstance really. Without out, the code will error if any of the inputs are scalar values instead of arrays. If you can guarantee the inputs will always be arrays, then yes it is unnecessary. Depending on circumstance you might cast to an array rather than check using `is_array` (and do the same on the second-level values too).

Answer (score 0):

As a purely native function solution, merge the arrays, then reindex each subarray.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FfjK5))

```
$a = [
    ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3],
    ['a' => 3, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 1],
];
$b = [
    ['d' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6],
    ['d' => 6, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 4],
];

var_export(
    array_map('array_values' array_merge($a, $b))
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 4,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 6,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 6,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 4,
  ),
)
```