# merge array in single array

Tags: php, codeigniter, array-merge

I have used the following code to get array and merge them.
On the print_r(arr1) I get following array.  In $arr I am trying to merge array but when i print_($arr) at the end of for-each I get same array.
Am I doing wrong array merge?
How can i combine or merge it?

```
foreach($q1->result_array() as $row4)
 {  
        $arr1 = $q1->result_array();
        echo"<pre>"; 

            print_r($arr1); 

        echo"</pre>";
        $arr = array_merge($arr, $arr1);
        echo "<br/>";
        $id = $row4['id'];
        $parent_id = $row4['parent_id'];
        if(!empty($arr1))
        {
            $this->showreply($id);                          
        }

 }
 print_r($arr);
```

Array which i get on print_r($arr1):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 69
            [reply] => First reply to Reply
            [parent_id] => 68
            [postid] => 0
            [us_id] => 41
            [added_by] => Shailesh
            [photo] => 9.jpg
            [added_on] => 2013-04-01 16:06:13
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 70
            [reply] => Reply to Nested Reply
            [parent_id] => 69
            [postid] => 0
            [us_id] => 41
            [added_by] => Shailesh
            [photo] => 9.jpg
            [added_on] => 2013-04-01 16:07:24
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 52
            [reply] => Reply on demand
            [parent_id] => 70
            [postid] => 0
            [us_id] => 50
            [added_by] => swapnil
            [photo] => 
            [added_on] => 2013-03-29 16:27:57
        )

)
```

Comment: what you want in $arr after finish foreach

Comment: @thumbernirmal:suppose i have above three array in Foreach and want that in single array.

Comment: Edited in this question please check that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array_merge($arr, $arr1);
```

This $arr variable was never initialized, so nothing plus $arr1 equals to $arr1.

Also why is this code inside a foreach?

Comment: :code inside foreach because each time i get new array and want to merge that in single array.

Comment: but each time you get a different `$row4` value, not a different $arr1!

Comment: :i have not show whole code but by calling showreply function i get above array.

Answer (score 1):

try this...i think this is what you are looking for

```
    foreach($q1->result_array() as $row4)
    {  
         $arr1 = $q1->result_array();

          $arr[]=$row4; 
    }

  print_r($arr)
```

Comment: :where i get merge result.

Comment: check i edited...not working then...print out the array you want after for each loop

Comment: want this type ofresult:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561987/php-merge-two-arrays