# How do I join arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I join arrays? For instance, I have several separate arrays of error below,

```
$message = array();
$message[] = array('error1' => '<error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 1." />');
$message[] = array('error2' => '<error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 2." />');
print_r($message);
```

result,

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [error1] => <error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 1." />
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [error2] => <error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 2." />
        )

)
```

But I actually want this,

```
Array (
    [error1] => <error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 1." />
    [error2] => <error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 2." />

)
```

Comment: that's not several arrays that's one array, you just left it to php to give the key value

Comment: `$message[$key] = $value`

Comment: This has been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535444/combine-two-arrays) [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170230/php-combine-two-associative-arrays-into-one-array) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561987/php-merge-two-arrays).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$message = array();
$message['error1'] =  '<error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 1." />';
$message['error2'] = '<error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 2." />';
print_r($message);
```

Comment: I think the array index must in quotes

Comment: should yes, must no, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Or use `array_merge`:

```
$newArray = array_merge($arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the keys don't overlap then you can safely join the arrays using the plus `+` operator.

```
$arr1 = array('error1' => '<error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 1." />');
$arr2 =  array('error2' => '<error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 2." />');

$message = $arr1 + $arr2;
```

Result:

```
Array (
    [error1] => <error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 1." />
    [error2] => <error elementid="file_rename" message="bla bla 2." />
)
```