# merge two different array and then display them php using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i am new here...I have two dynamic arrays..their columns are different

First Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 102
            [parent_id] => 94
            [dir_name] => games
            [size] => 
            [owner_id] => 10
            [shared_link] => http://creativevisionintl.com/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/games
            [shared] => 0
            [comment] => 
            [add_date] =>  07/30/2013 02:43 AM
            [update_date] =>  07/30/2013 02:43 AM
            [path] => /home1/creatkj8/public_html/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/games
            [trash_status] => 1
            [password] => 
            [expires_after] => 0
            [allow_uploading] => 0
            [share_date] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 122
            [parent_id] => 94
            [dir_name] => New Folder
            [size] => 777835
            [owner_id] => 10
            [shared_link] => http://creativevisionintl.com/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/New Folder
            [shared] => 0
            [comment] => 
            [add_date] =>  08/16/2013 08:31 AM
            [update_date] =>  08/16/2013 08:31 AM
            [path] => /home1/creatkj8/public_html/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/New Folder
            [trash_status] => 1
            [password] => 
            [expires_after] => 0
            [allow_uploading] => 0
            [share_date] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 98
            [parent_id] => 94
            [dir_name] => Videos
            [size] => 
            [owner_id] => 10
            [shared_link] => http://creativevisionintl.com/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/Videos/
            [shared] => 0
            [comment] => 
            [add_date] =>  07/30/2013 02:38 AM
            [update_date] =>  07/30/2013 02:38 AM
            [path] => /home1/creatkj8/public_html/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/Videos/
            [trash_status] => 1
            [password] => 
            [expires_after] => 0
            [allow_uploading] => 0
            [share_date] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 97
            [parent_id] => 94
            [dir_name] => Pictures
            [size] => 
            [owner_id] => 10
            [shared_link] => http://creativevisionintl.com/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/Pictures/
            [shared] => 0
            [comment] => 
            [add_date] =>  07/30/2013 02:38 AM
            [update_date] =>  07/30/2013 02:38 AM
            [path] => /home1/creatkj8/public_html/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/Pictures/
            [trash_status] => 1
            [password] => 
            [expires_after] => 0
            [allow_uploading] => 0
            [share_date] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 95
            [parent_id] => 94
            [dir_name] => Documents
            [size] => 
            [owner_id] => 10
            [shared_link] => http://creativevisionintl.com/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/Documents/
            [shared] => 1
            [comment] => 
            [add_date] =>  07/30/2013 02:38 AM
            [update_date] =>  07/30/2013 02:38 AM
            [path] => /home1/creatkj8/public_html/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/Documents/
            [trash_status] => 1
            [password] => 123456
            [expires_after] => 5
            [allow_uploading] => 0
            [share_date] => 13-09-2013
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 96
            [parent_id] => 94
            [dir_name] => Music
            [size] => 
            [owner_id] => 10
            [shared_link] => http://creativevisionintl.com/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/Music/
            [shared] => 0
            [comment] => dfdf
            [add_date] =>  07/30/2013 02:38 AM
            [update_date] =>  07/30/2013 02:38 AM
            [path] => /home1/creatkj8/public_html/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/Music/
            [trash_status] => 1
            [password] => 
            [expires_after] => 0
            [allow_uploading] => 0
            [share_date] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 233
            [parent_id] => 94
            [dir_name] => test
            [size] => 3945040
            [owner_id] => 10
            [shared_link] => http://creativevisionintl.com/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/test
            [shared] => 0
            [comment] => 
            [add_date] =>  09/06/2013 09:16 AM
            [update_date] =>  09/06/2013 09:16 AM
            [path] => /home1/creatkj8/public_html/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/test
            [trash_status] => 1
            [password] => 
            [expires_after] => 0
            [allow_uploading] => 0
            [share_date] => 
        )

)
```

2nd array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 118
            [name] => Desert.jpg
            [size] => 845941
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [ext] => jpg
            [shared] => 1
            [shared_link] => http://creativevisionintl.com/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home//Desert.jpg
            [comment] => 
            [owner_id] => 10
            [dir_id] => 94
            [path] => /home1/creatkj8/public_html/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/Home/Desert.jpg
            [del_path] => /home1/creatkj8/public_html/dev/fwingo/usersdata/saqlain/HomeDesert.jpg
            [dated] =>  09/05/2013 07:15 AM
            [trash_status] => 1
            [password] => 
            [expires_after] => 2
            [share_date] => 06-09-2013
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 120
            [name] => test.zip
            [size] => 4096
            [type] => Zip Archeive
            [ext] => zip
            [shared] => 0
            [shared_link] => /Documentstest.zip
            [comment] => 
            [owner_id] => 10
            [dir_id] => 94
            [path] => /Documentstest.zip
            [del_path] => /Documentstest.zip
            [dated] =>  09/06/2013 09:21 AM
            [trash_status] => 1
            [password] => 
            [expires_after] => 0
            [share_date] => 
        )

)
```

Note: i want to merge both arrays and after that display them using foreach loop both arrays have different columns.
Thanks. plz urgent replay.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561987/php-merge-two-arrays

Comment: @fluminis in my case this is different and i want merge them and after that display them in a table using for each or any loop both array have different indexes. :)

Comment: Don't ever say "urgent" here, please. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6513 for a good explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

For example merge two arrays

```
$a = array("red","green","yellow");
$b = array("a","b","c");
$c = array_merge($a,$b);

print_r($c);

foreach ($c as $key => $value) {
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to merge the arrays into one :

```
//Merge the arrays
$arrayEnd = array(); // define an array that will contain all the rows

    //iterate on the first array assuming its name is $array1
foreach($array1 as $val) {
            //add the current line named $val to the resulting array
    $arrayEnd[] = $val;
}
    //iterate on the first array assuming its name is $array1
foreach($array1 as $val) {
            //add the current line named $val to the resulting array
    $arrayEnd[] = $val;
}
```

Then you just need to iterate through the resulting array:

```
//Display the resulting array
foreach($arrayEnd as $val) {
    echo $val['id']." - ".$val['name'];
}
```

Comment: plz explain little more i am new here.. :)

Answer (score 0):

let say `$a` is your first array and `$b` is your 2nd array, then for merging them you can do it by below code.

```
$master = array_merge($a,$b);
```

then use foreach loop for getting their content like below

```
foreach($master as $item){
   echo $item;
}
```