# Combine 2 place request to get postal code

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-places-api

I would like to combine two place-api calls in one to get further information about listings.

Example:

My first script request provides Name and Address from the API.  However, the Placesearch API does not provide the postal code or other information I need.

My current script shows me this:

```
name;adress,lnt,lng,place_id
```

but I need more information for each listing, like the postal code, which not included here.

How can I include a 2nd API call for each place_id and display the postal code?

```php
$apikey = 'KEY';

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.374,10.1495&rankby=distance&name=keyword&language=de&key=$apikey";

$json = file_get_contents($url);

$obj = json_decode($json, true);

for($i=0; $i<count($obj['results']); $i++) {
    echo "" . $obj['results'][$i]['name'] . ";" . $obj['results'][$i]['vicinity'] . ";" . $obj['results'][$i]['geometry']['location']['lat'] . ";" . $obj['results'][$i]['geometry']['location']['lng'] . ";" . $obj['results'][$i]['place_id'] . DISPLaY POSTCODE "<BR>";
};
```

I know, I need to run this query for each place_id:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=$place_id=name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

But how can I combine it together with the first results?  I need:

```
Name;Adress;Postcode;LAT;LNG;
```

Update:

1st request:

```php
$apikey = 'KEY';

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.374,10.1495&rankby=distance&name=keyword&language=de&key=$apikey";

$json = file_get_contents($url);

$obj = json_decode($json, true);

for($i=0; $i<count($obj['results']); $i++) {
    echo "" . $obj['results'][$i]['name'] . ";" . $obj['results'][$i]['vicinity'] . ";" . $obj['results'][$i]['geometry']['location']['lat'] . ";" . $obj['results'][$i]['geometry']['location']['lng'] . ";" . $obj['results'][$i]['place_id'] . DISPLaY POSTCODE "<BR>";
};
```

this is one ex response from the first request, the ChIJidzOXaLBpEcRxEKHcEN9fuo is the place id which i have to request the details:

```php
Flinsberger Sportplatz;Heilbad Heiligenstadt;51.3163051;10.1929773;ChIJidzOXaLBpEcRxEKHcEN9fuo
```

this is api call shows the neede details, which i need and can access:

```php
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJidzOXaLBpEcRxEKHcEN9fuo=name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

i need to include the 2nd request in the 1st, to get for ex. the postalcode for the specific item, which is my problem i dont know.

and the result should be:
name,adress,postalcode, ... , ... ,...

Comment: Read this: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details.  It shows you that you can use the `address_components` field from the JSON response to find the postal code.  That link shows you how to build the query URL when you know the place_id.

Comment: Hey, yes i know this page, and i know how to get the correct responses. my problem is how to put this requests together, so i get my needed format.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Ok then you have 2 calls, hence 2 JSON results.  Parse both.  Lets say `$obj1` and `$obj2`.  Get some information from `$obj1`, other from `$obj2` to defile your place.  Each place could have an array assigned to it to store it's information.  If you poste sample JSON responses in your question, we could show you how.  FYI: do not post code in comments, formatting is lost.  Edit the question instead.

Comment: You cannot do it in one request.  The first one provides the place_id, the second one the details of the place_id.  Two requests, two results, combined in your code.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your help, i have updated the first post, and hope you can understand it ... sorry again for the bad english ... 

i know i have to combine both together, to get the result but i dont know how :)

thanks again dude :)

Comment: okay this i understand, can you give me an example how i can combined it ?

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, I came up with this.  Note that I do not have an API key myself to test, the the idea is there.  You might have to adjust the reference to `$obj2` based on the result of the `json_decode` function for the second query (the one in the loop).

```
<?php

$apikey = 'KEY';

$url1 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.374,10.1495&rankby=distance&name=keyword&language=de&key=$apikey";
$json1 = file_get_contents($url1);
$obj1 = json_decode($json1, true);

for( $i = 0; $i < count($obj1['results']); $i++) 
{
    $place_id = $obj1['results'][$i]['place_id'];

    $url2 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?json&key=" .$apikey . "&placeid=" . $place_id . "&fields=address_component"
    $json2 = file_get_contents($url2);
    $obj2 = json_decode($json2, true);

    echo "" . $obj1['results'][$i]['name'] . ";" . $obj1['results'][$i]['vicinity'] . ";" . $obj1['results'][$i]['geometry']['location']['lat'] . ";" . $obj1['results'][$i]['geometry']['location']['lng'] . ";" . $obj1['results'][$i]['place_id'] . $obj2['result']['address_components']['postal_code'] . "<br>";
};

?>
```

The idea is you get the information you want form `$obj1` and `$obj2` based on the results of the 2 queries.

Comment: Hey, i think this looks awesome will try it after a coffee :) but yes looks good ... in mean while in view of your answers i found this what maybe worked to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176816/merge-two-different-array-and-then-display-them-php-using-foreach

but i will try your example first ... thanks a lot

Comment: Hi yes you could merge the arrays together, and then get all the information from that single array.  Both work.