# PHP Array Merge two Arrays with the same value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP, and I'm trying to merge the following two arrays into one array, matching the same CODE value:

```
Array(1)
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => CODE11
            [1] => NAME
            [2] => ADDRESS
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => CODE23
            [1] => NAME
            [2] => ADDRESS
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => CODE25
            [1] => NAME
            [2] => ADDRESS
        )
)
```

and

```
Array(2)
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => CODE43
            [1] => CITY
            [2] => COUNTRY
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => CODE25
            [1] => CITY
            [2] => COUNTRY
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => CODE89
            [1] => CITY
            [2] => COUNTRY
        )
)
```

into this new array:

```
Result
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => CODE25
            [1] => NAME
            [2] => ADDRESS
            [3] => CITY
            [4] => COUNTRY
        )
)
```

As you can see, only CODE25 matches on both arrays. How do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561987/php-merge-two-arrays?rq=1

Comment: This doesn't look similar to that question at all. The titles are similar, but that's it.

Comment: We can't tell you how to fix your code if you don't post it.

Comment: Why aren't you using associative arrays?

Answer (score 2):

```
$hash = array();
// First create an associative array from $array1 using the CODE as the key
foreach ($array1 as $el) {
    $hash[$el[0]] = $el;
}
// Then append the data from $array2 to matching elements
foreach ($array2 as $el) {
    if (isset($hash[$el[0]])) {
        $hash[$el[0]] = array_merge($hash[$el[0]], array_slice($el, 1));
    }
}
// Now find the elements that were matched and return them as an ordinary array
$new_array = array_values(array_filter($hash, function($x) { return count($x) > 3; }));
```

Comment: +1 for nice and simple algorithm, faster than mine :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! but i couldn´t make it work! actually each one of my 2 arrays have 15.000 sub arrays and the algorithm just return 1 result =(

Comment: Can you post some sample data with `var_export()` so I can try running my script with it?

Answer (score 0):

We could do this with less code by using native PHP functions, but instead of that and because you're learning, let's try a very basic way:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1)
{
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        if ($value1[0] == $value2[0])
            $result[] = array(
                $value1[0],
                $value1[1],
                $value1[2],
                $value2[1],
                $value2[2]
            );
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: this is not a very efficient algorithm. But for a short amount of data (`$array1` and `$array2` < 20,000 keys each), it will do the trick with no pain. See [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for more informations about that.

Comment: You're copying the CODE into the result twice.

Comment: Tried your code..no luck. Actually i´m working with 15.000 arrays and the code i was using was similiar to this:


`foreach($array1 as $value)
{
  foreach($array2 as $value1)
  {
    if($value['0'] == $value1[0])
  {
     do something....;
  }
 }
}`
But my pc i7 seems it can´t handle it =(

Comment: Great! So you've got a BIG example of how much it matters to find a good algorithm