# how to store multiple checkbox value in database table

Tags: php, arrays

I am explaining my scenario as

i have form in which adding checkbox row multiple times.
in first row checkbox values from Monday to Sunday
In second row checkbox values also from monday to sunday.
I mean to say every row handling on Add Button.
Below is the view.php code

```
<div id="myDIV1" class="form-group  col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><label for="day" class="control-label">Day</label><br><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Monday">Monday</label><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Tuesday">Tuesday</label><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Wednesday">Wednesday</label><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Thursday">Thursday</label><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Friday">Friday</label><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Saturday">Saturday</label><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Sunday">Sunday</label><?php echo form_error('day'); ?></div>
```

Below is the controller code.....

```
$day = implode(',', $this->input->post('day'));
```

i am using implode bcoz suppose in the first row i have checked Monday and Sunday so it will give me value as Monday, Sunday

My Scenario is i have checked Monday, Sunday from first row
and also checked Tuesday, Wednesday from secound row

According to my code i am getting result as Monday, Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday in $day
But i want to store Monday, Sunday in first row of table and Tuesday, Wednesday in second row of table.
I am sharing the image link as below
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k8bYsRUJFo9mI2AY6D-d4MGHEoWudB7q

In the image Add Date & Time is dynamic.

Plz guide me for the same.
Thanks

Comment: you can use `array_merge`

Comment: Can you share the proper inputs? What you show as being "one" input array is actually two

Comment: What does `$input` actually look like? Is it an array of arrays, or do you actually have those arrays in individual variables?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/77aKS works fine for me

Comment: Blank page means some error. Please post full related code.

Comment: __Code__, not php version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php merge  two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561987/php-merge-two-arrays)

Comment: @AmodKumar `<?php
$a = array(14);
$b = array(15);
$result = call_user_func_array("array_merge", array($a,$b));
print_r($result);
?>`

Comment: https://3v4l.org/L6cEJ your error is somewhere else. Enable error reporting and check.

Comment: @AmodKumar we don't need your scenario, we need __exact code which is NOT working__.

Comment: I think the array posted is created in a loop and he tries to merge after the loop. That is why he has two seperate arrays in the outpiut

Comment: We can help you Amod but we need your code. If you don't give us the code then this question will be closed

Comment: You have been a member here long enough to know you can edit your posts? When that link stops working your question is useless

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge` method: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```php
<?php

$array = array("1" );
$otherArray = array("2");

$result = array_merge($array, $otherArray);

print_r($result);
```

see live code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7fb9da6de4fa9d0a8b220a06d2a59e9007655df1

Comment: This is not what op has. Op has one array, not two arrays

Comment: He has two arrays

Comment: According to OP he has one multidimensional array.

Comment: You didn't read correctly. He want a result consist of two items in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Surely just `array_merge` will suffice?

```
    $a=[14];
    $b=[18];
    $c=[23];
    $d=[44];
    $e=[27];
    $f=[31];
    $g=[99];


    $out=array_merge($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g);
    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($out,true));
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 18
    [2] => 23
    [3] => 44
    [4] => 27
    [5] => 31
    [6] => 99
)
```

Answer (score 0):

OP asks about merging arrays from one array. We don't know how many arrays there, so we need to use array_walk_recursive function. Pass $result from public scope by reference(!) in anonymous function and store in it all inner arrays values

```
$a = [[1], [2, 3]];

$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($a, function($value) use (&$result){
    $result[] = $value;
});
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why call_user_func?

```
$a = array(14);
$b = array(18);
$merged = array_merge($a,$b);
```